# PyParsing parsing section with/without space

Tags: pyparsing

I want to parse variables in the following code with or without space in an existing line. If I do not have space, I can not distinguish the variable from a string

```py
from pyparsing import *
Jinja_str_all       = NotAny(Regex(r"{{"))+Word(printables)
Jinja_str_all1      = Word(printables)
Jinja_str           = Word(alphas)
Jinja_Var_start     = Regex(r"{{")
Jinja_Var_end       = Regex(r"}}")
test1 = """
{{ variable }}
{{variable}}
aldkjflsdf {{ variable }}
aldkjflsdf{{ variable }}
aldkjflsdf  {{ variable }} asdflskdfjlj {{ bbb }}
aldkjflsdf{{ variable }}asdflskdfjlj{{ bbb }}sdfsdfwerwr"""

test2 = "aldkjflsdf {{ variable }}"
line_Variable = ZeroOrMore(Jinja_str_all) + Group(Jinja_Var_start+OneOrMore(Jinja_str) + Jinja_Var_end) + ZeroOrMore(Jinja_str_all)

for a in test1.split("\n"):
    print(a)
    print(line_Variable.parseString(a))
```

it should be possible to parse out the variables in all variations

Answer (score 0):

This is the expression that is causing the run-on in parsing the names immediately before the '{' character:

```
Jinja_str_all       = NotAny(Regex(r"{{"))+Word(printables)
```

Pyparsing, unlike regex, does *no* implicit backtracking. The `Word` class is especially greedy, so `Word(printables)` is going to consume every non-space character up to the end of the line, so that includes the following '{' character.

If I understand your format, you do not want to include '{}' characters in these names, but to use them for grouping and delimiters, so you should exclude them from the list of characters the Word should match on.

This is easily done adding the `excludeChars` argument to `Word`:

```
Jinja_str_all       = NotAny(Regex(r"{{"))+Word(printables, excludeChars='{}')
```

`line_variable` is also a bit more complicated than it needs to be. You just need to match one or more `Jinja_str_all` OR the grouped expression:

```
line_Variable = OneOrMore(Jinja_str_all 
                 | Group(Jinja_Var_start 
                         + OneOrMore(Jinja_str)
                         + Jinja_Var_end)
                )
```

Using the new ellipsis notation, you can also write this as:

```
line_Variable = (Jinja_str_all 
                 | Group(Jinja_Var_start 
                         + Jinja_str[1, ...]
                         + Jinja_Var_end)
                )[1, ...]
```

I chose to use `runTests` to test your input strings:

```
line_Variable[...].runTests(test1)
```

This runs the expression on each line in the test1 variable, and dumps the parsed result, or shows where the parsing goes astray:

```
{{ variable }}
[['{{', 'variable', '}}']]
[0]:
  ['{{', 'variable', '}}']

{{variable}}
[['{{', 'variable', '}}']]
[0]:
  ['{{', 'variable', '}}']

aldkjflsdf {{ variable }}
['aldkjflsdf', ['{{', 'variable', '}}']]
[0]:
  aldkjflsdf
[1]:
  ['{{', 'variable', '}}']

aldkjflsdf{{ variable }}
['aldkjflsdf', ['{{', 'variable', '}}']]
[0]:
  aldkjflsdf
[1]:
  ['{{', 'variable', '}}']

aldkjflsdf  {{ variable }} asdflskdfjlj {{ bbb }}
['aldkjflsdf', ['{{', 'variable', '}}'], 'asdflskdfjlj', ['{{', 'bbb', '}}']]
[0]:
  aldkjflsdf
[1]:
  ['{{', 'variable', '}}']
[2]:
  asdflskdfjlj
[3]:
  ['{{', 'bbb', '}}']

aldkjflsdf{{ variable }}asdflskdfjlj{{ bbb }}sdfsdfwerwr
['aldkjflsdf', ['{{', 'variable', '}}'], 'asdflskdfjlj', ['{{', 'bbb', '}}'], 'sdfsdfwerwr']
[0]:
  aldkjflsdf
[1]:
  ['{{', 'variable', '}}']
[2]:
  asdflskdfjlj
[3]:
  ['{{', 'bbb', '}}']
[4]:
  sdfsdfwerwr
```

(I just got tired of writing those little test loops for every parser demo...)